# Google Colab stops the cell that is running my train.py code seemingly random

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, google-colaboratory

[Colab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRQqb.jpg)
I am using tensorflow 1.15.2 and training an object detection model in google colab. When I run the code -

```
!python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config
```

it will work as intended for a short period of time. I either get through only 200 iterations or it could go 7000 then show ^c at the end, signifying that it stopped the training.

I have heard about the session disconnecting so i set an auto clicker to keep the page active but it still stops. Any help with keeping it from stopping will greatly appreciated.

EDIT: here is the link to the notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KkLSaJCoiN4P0HKg-oEMTG9kfSJl6BqM

Comment: It would be more clear to us if you can attach a screenshot of how your program is crashing.

Comment: @Saimon added the photo

Comment: Try changing the hardware accelerator by going to `runtime>change runtime type>Hardware Accelerator` and change `None` to `GPU`.

Comment: @Saimon Already did so, there were times where I got 40k+ into the training and it was fine. It just is random.  Would slow internet  be the cause?

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: @BobSmith done.

Comment: The notebook depends on private data in Drive. Can you reproduce the problem with public data?

Comment: @BobSmith how would you like me to do that? make share the google drive folder I am working out of?

Comment: @CharlieWatson Did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same issue (using GDrive).

Comment: @TechySharnav yes I did, I found that I was running out of memory, look up how to force google colab to give you 25 gigs of ram instead of the 12 that it normally starts out with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I was running out of memory, you need to force google colab to give you 25 gigs of ram instead of the 12 that it normally starts out with.